# What is the distinction between the two translations of "Feind"?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

This perhaps is more appropriate for the English language stackexchange, but it's a question about a particular translation. Pardon my ignorance of the language.

In a translation of a "The Concept of the Political", the translator notes the following:

"Since Schmitt identified himself with the epoch of the national sovereign state with its *jus publicum Europaeum*, he used the term *Feind* in the enemy and not the foe sense."

It was my understanding that foe and enemy were synonymous! But these seem to be considered two separate translations (eg, when using Google Translate, it gives both foe and enemy as possible translations, and different words as synonyms depending on the interpretation).

What is the difference between the two possible translations of the word "Feind"?

Comment: You mentioned it yourself already: This is not a question about the German language at all. That's why I vote to close, because it requires knowledge of the English language rather than of the German language. Your question is simply: "What is the difference between *enemy* and *foe*?"

Comment: To most native English speakers, there is no difference (I do not recognize one). Yet Feind appears to have two meanings, translated as those two words. This is the contradiction I don't know how to resolve. So it seems clearest to ask: what does Feind mean?

Comment: Maybe you should provide some more context. Maybe someone with more knowledge of Carl Schmitt could understand what the translator meant.

Comment: This exact question has already been asked on [ell.stackexchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70282/what-is-the-difference-between-foe-and-enemy)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As you write yourself in the comment that your real question is about any nuance of Feind - maybe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Feind is of help? Or just rewrite your question and note down the nuances when to use foe and when to use enemy?

Comment: Please re-write your question. I disagree that it was shut down. You want to know the differences of German connotations here. And I do not really see it even as a German native. The English translation reference question actually derailed your question, made it easy target to the habitual closers on SE. Funny this.